# the Support function of reuleaux triangle

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geometric-construction

I am looking for the explicit support functions (and also  reuleaux polygones )

but all I find is general properties , could you give a Book or a paper when can i found the expolicit support functions of reuleaux triangle ?

thank you in advance